# How to change section text in INI file using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ini

I have to change the section in an ini-file using Word VBA.

I know how to change the values of the keys, but can anyone tell me how to  change the value of a section (the first section = the only section)? 
In the example below I like to change OldName in NewName.

[Offices]
Office1=OldName

[OldName]
Key1=value
Key2=value
etc.

Thanks,
Kem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to replace text in any text file

```
Public Sub Test()

    ReplaceInTXT "C:\folder\file.ini", "[OldName]", "[NewName]"

End Sub

Public Sub ReplaceInTXT(sFileName As String, sFind As String, sReplace As String)

    Dim Content As String
    Dim hFile As Long

    hFile = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As #hFile
    Content = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
    Close #hFile

    Content = Replace(Content, sFind, sReplace)

    Open sFileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, Content
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Please make sure to have a backup first. I don't want to mess up the file

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.